# Eclipse não gera a classe R

Tags: android

Ultimamente não estou conseguindo mais desenvolver nada, pois o ADT Eclipse está problemático, já baixei vários, em computadores diferentes e o erro persiste.

Ao criar qualquer projeto inferior ao 4.0, o eclipse não gera a classe R.
Alguém sabe o que pode ser isso? Já dei clean, verifiquei o SDK, baixei outro ADT , instalei praticamente tudo la no SDK Manager, e nada.

Comment: Um dos motivos de não gerar este arquivo pode estar relacionado com erro em algum dos seus arquivos XML. Você já conferiu para ver se não existe alguma falha que não tenha visto antes?

Comment: Que falha? pois eu crio um projeto e ja vem com o erro, ja verifiquei os xml sim e não vejo nada errado.

Comment: Tente dar uma olhada nesse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating

Comment: Ja tinha visto, ja tentei esses passos mas sem sucesso. Mas sempre funcionou tudo aqui, e agora ta dando esse erro, tanto na empresa quanto na minha casa. Quando cria o projeto, cria apenas o buildConfig, mas nada de R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando alguma biblioteca/projeto como dependência do seu projeto? As vezes, quando há algum erro com uma dependência, a classe R realmente não é gerada. Um exemplo clássico é quando você usa a biblioteca de suporte v7, que depende da v4 e você esquece de colocar a v4 como dependência da v7. Neste caso, o seu projeto não gera a classe R porque seu projeto faz referências a recursos definidos na biblioteca de suporte v4 mas ele não consegue achar.

Se você estiver usando a biblioteca de compatibilidade v7, verifique se você seguiu todos os passos mostrados no site de [Support Library Setup do Android](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

Siga o tutorial apresentado na seção **"Adding libraries with resources"** 
porque como seu problema é na hora de gerar a classe R, você necessita das referências aos resources das bibliotecas.

Comment: Acho que é isso, pois estou criando projetos para 2.2/ 2.3 , criei aqui com 4.4 e deu certo! mas preciso criar projetos 2.2 , como faço para criar ou importar 2.2? quando importo tambem da erro no style.xml la no theme.light, ja fiz as configurações do appcompat v7 mas nao consigo rodar

Comment: no properties dos projetos 2.2, fica assim target=android-20
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7

Comment: Você tá usando o appcompat_v7? Se sim, tentou importar o appcompat_v4 também? Vê se o a edição que eu fiz na minha resposta te ajuda. Se não, explica exatamente que bibliotecas de compatibilidade você tá usando pra eu ajudar certinho.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontecei comigo no Linux. Uma solução na época que encontrei foi trocar de distro ou baixar o eclipse, não o adt, e instalar o plugin a moda antiga!

Você já fez isso? Se não, faça o seguinte: baixe o eclipse Juno, vá em Help -> Install New Software, no botão Add, coloque um nome qualquer e no campo abaixo, adicione esse link, **https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/** . Marque as opções que aparecerem, e instale normalmente! Reinicie o eclipse, crie um projeto e comente aqui se funcionou!

Boa sorte!

Comment: Eu baixei o eclipse Luna ( ultima versão) e fiz isso, da a mesma coisa. Acabei de testar em um terceiro computador baixando o adt, e o problema persiste!  infelizmente nao tenho como programar nada

Comment: rapaz.. bizarro isso que está acontecendo contigo viu?! As últimas soluções que vejo é usar o Android Studio ou o NetBeans configurado para Android.

Answer (score 0):

não sei se vc conseguiu solucionar seu problema, mas quebrando um pouco a cabeça acabei descobrindo um jeito de burlar esse problema...

Eu criei no novo projeto, com a versão 4.0 e depois de criado assim a Classe R é criada normalmente, depois fui em propriedades do projeto e alterei para 2.3.3 e funcionou...

espero ter ajudado